# Графики в matplotlib накладываются друг на друга

Tags: python, matplotlib

Такая проблема что я использую дискорд.py и у меня при вызове несколько раз функций графики накладываются друг на друга.
вот код

```
@client.command()
async def stat(ctx):

    ibv = randint(1, 20)
    listc = []
    listm = []
    for i in range(ibv):
        listc.append(i)
    for i in range(ibv):
        listm.append(randint(1, 20))

    plt.plot(listc, listm)
    rand = randint(1, 10)


    plt.savefig("graf.png")
    await ctx.send(file = discord.File(fp = f'graf.png'))
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

После plt.savefig("graf.png") нужно добавить

```
plt.close()
```

Тогда в графики не будет ничего добавляться